# Deciding on a data model based on something’s attributes and their properties

Tags: nlp, data-science-model

Considering something with these fields:

1. A category
2. A channel
3. A post

Where a post has:

1. A title
2. A body
3. Tags
4. The ability to write messages/comments on the post
5. The ability to link to other posts in fields of type “body” (body, and comments)

Let’s say you ideally want a model that can automatically turn information into the above format.

Is there an exact way to specify the properties of the data model, so the model understands the linguistic character or function of each field?

I mean, I guess I could use JSON, for each value. But to express the relationships they have to each other, I guess GraphML, or JSON Graph?

Or should I use UML?

I am wondering if for it to be universal, should it try to express what property each thing has in a more universal way, like a proof assistant language, like Agda?